# Производительность таблицы с полями типа TEXT

Tags: база-данных, производительность, mysql

Стоит ли использовать таблицу MySQL в которой все поля типа TEXT NULL, и выборка из неё будет производится с использованием LIMIT? Отразится ли это на производительности?

Есть некий аггрегирующий результат выборки, и обработка этого результата занимает некоторое время, в течение которого крайне нежелательно изменять эти выбранные данные. Планирую весь результат сохранить во временной таблице, для последующей обработки.

Проблема в том, что  результат получается разный, из-за динамически формируемых полей в этом результате. Список полей создаю на основе первой строки результата. Определение типов для каждого поля не работает правильно, потому что на основе одной строки невозможно точно определить тип.

Comment: `*glitch*`

Comment: ниче не понял) может для наглядности выложите таблицы и что вам нада из них получать?

Comment: Суть вопроса такая: как mysql относится к таблице в которой все поля типа text, индекс не назначен. Выборка из этой таблицы производится порциями - LIMIT n, 100. Данные в этой таблице разные может быть и null, может быть и несколько строчек текста. 

Загвоздка в том, что нельзя заранее точно определить какие именно названия полей и какой именно набор данных будет в этой таблице.

Comment: Если брать в общем виде - вам нужно хранилище абстрактных данных, которые вы хотите как-то разбирать на клиенте?

Предложенное вами решение не самое быстрое... но с другой стороны mysql изначально использует записи переменной длинны... поэтому это не так заметно, как на больших БД.

Именно для вашего решения лучше пользовать nosql базы данных.

Но описание структуры данных для клиента-парсера желательно все-таки хранить. Ну хотябы где-то отдельно... в XML-виде например.

Comment: Но описание структуры данных для клиента-парсера желательно все-таки хранить. Ну хотябы где-то отдельно... в XML-виде например, чтоб небыло "Определение типов для каждого поля не работает правильно". Если на момент запуска парсера вы не знаете, что ж он должен парсеристь... то в архитектуре решения есть бока.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Да, спасибо, уже решил вопрос. Наиболее вероятные типы полей определил жёстко, для остальных - оставил неопределённость (text). Проиводительность довольно приемлимая. Возможно позже вернусь к вопросу и доработаю.